# How do I make a downloaded flash player the default program with which to open .swf files?

Tags: flash, default-programs

I downloaded a Flash player and I'm trying to make it the default app to open .swf files in Ubuntu 20.04. It's a standalone player and doesn't show on Applications. How do I do that?